# Dual Selection sort (with pointers) crashes program

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, selection

I just started programming again and I still can't get the hang of pointers. I'm trying to do a selection sort with descending test scores with names "attached" to the test score. When I use the selection sort with just the scores, it works perfectly, but when I basically write the same code for the names that go along with their respective test scores, the program crashes. Here's the function:

```
void sortScores (double scores[], int num, string names[])
{
   int startScan, maxIndex;
   double* maxValue;
   string* tempName;

   for (startScan = 0; startScan < (num - 1); startScan++)
   {
       maxIndex = startScan;
       *maxValue = scores[startScan];
       *tempName = names[startScan];
       for (int index = (startScan + 1); index < num; index++)
       {
          if (scores[index] > *maxValue)
          {
             *maxValue = scores[index];
             *tempName = names[index];
             maxIndex = index;
          }
      }
      scores[maxIndex] = scores[startScan];
      names[maxIndex] = names[startScan];
      scores[startScan] = *maxValue;
      names[startScan] = *tempName;
  }

 // for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
   // cout << scores[i] << "   " << names[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxValue` and `tempName` should not be pointers. Really, you only got this working by pure chance, because dereferencing unitialized pointers is constituted "undefined behavior." Try this:

```
void sortScores (double scores[], int num, string names[])
{
    int startScan, maxIndex;
    double maxValue;
    string tempName;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (num - 1); startScan++)
    {
        maxIndex = startScan;
        maxValue = scores[startScan];
        tempName = names[startScan];
        for (int index = (startScan + 1); index < num; index++)
        {
            if (scores[index] > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = scores[index];
                tempName = names[index];
                maxIndex = index;
            }
        }
        scores[maxIndex] = scores[startScan];
        names[maxIndex] = names[startScan];
        scores[startScan] = maxValue;
        names[startScan] = tempName;
    }

    // for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    // cout << scores[i] << "   " << names[i] << endl;
}
```